# Which version of the JAX-RS API is supported by TomEE 8.0? JAX-RS 2.0 or JAX-RS 2.1?

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-8, jersey-test-framework, tomee-8

According to the [TomEE Download Page](https://tomee.apache.org/download.html), TomEE 8.0 implements the APIs of [Java EE 8](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-ee-8.html) and [MicroProfile 2.0](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.microprofile/releases/microprofile-2.0). Part of these specifications is the API JAX-RS 2.1.

Recently, however, I ran into `ClassNotFoundExceptions` when trying to use the the Jersey Testframework (Version 2.38), which also is based on JAX-RS 2.1. When I analyzed this problem, I found that Jersey introduced a dependency jakarta.ws.rs-api-2.1.6.jar, that contained different versions of the API classes than the ones from TomEE 8.0 (javaee-api-8.0-5.jar from org.apache.tomee:javaee-api:8.0-5). Furthermore, the source code from the latter library is commented with *Apache Geronimo JAX-RS Spec 2.0*. On the other hand, a javaee-api-8.0.jar from Oracle (javax:javaee-api:8.0) contains the same classes as the Jersey dependency.

So from this, it looks like TomEE is in fact based on JAX-RS 2.0. Can anybody shed a light on this discrepancy?